# Super complicated SQL query

Tags: mysql

Have an article model, each article has an author and publisher (both are tables). A user can follow authors and publishers.

User -> Follow -> Author or Publisher -> Article

I want to find all the articles by the authors and publishers they are following.

```
SELECT articles.*, articles2.* FROM follows 
INNER JOIN articles ON follows.author_id = articles.author_id
INNER JOIN articles AS articles2 ON follows.publisher_id = articles2.publisher_id
WHERE follows.user_id = 1
```

Can I get all the articles into 1 query? If so how? If not can I combine two queries and then order them?

Comment: mysql and sql have some different in syntax, please select right tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.* from follows f
inner join articles a on (a.author_id = f.author_id or a.publisher_id=f.publisher_id)
where f.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Nice answer ;), you were 4 seconds faster!

Comment: Guess it wasn't that hard after all. thanks a ton. Spent the last 3 hours trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT articles.*, articles2.* FROM follows 
INNER JOIN articles ON (follows.author_id = articles.author_id OR follows.publisher_id = articles.publisher_id)
WHERE follows.user_id = 1
```

That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT articles.* FROM follows,articles
WHERE follows.user_id = 1 
AND (follows.author_id = articles.author_id 
     OR follows.publisher_id = articles2.publisher_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head:

SELECT articles.* FROM follows 
INNER JOIN articles ON follows.author_id = articles.author_id
WHERE follows.user_id = 1

UNION

SELECT articles.* FROM follows 
INNER JOIN articles ON follows.publisher_id = articles.publisher_id
WHERE follows.user_id = 1
order by articles.title

Answer (score 0):

SELECT articles.* FROM follows  INNER JOIN articles ON follows.author_id = articles.author_id

union all

SELECT articles2.* FROM follows INNER JOIN articles AS articles2 ON follows.publisher_id = articles2.publisher_id

Something like that.